# Using a custom type 1 font no longer working

Tags: lilypond

I can no longer get lilypond to typeset using my custom Sabon font. I have *.pfb files I bought
some years ago and have them installed in /path-to-home-directory/.fonts

The code I have below worked just fine for over three years, but no longer works after
updating to LilyPond 2.24.3.

I have run

fc-cache -fv

and, moreover,

lilypond -dshow-available-fonts

lists the various Sabon families.

But if I put this directive in my lilypond file, the lyrics are typeset with the default sans font instead of Sabon.

\paper
{
#(define fonts
(make-pango-font-tree
"Sabon"
"Sans"
"Mono"
(/ 20 20)
)
)
}

Has there been a change in how lilypond handles fonts?

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's right. That's the point. Lilypond ignores the appointed serif font Sabon and goes to the sans font instead.

Comment: I just looked at the documentation for make-pango-font-tree. Please ignore my first comment.

Comment: You might need to give the complete font name e.g. "Sabon Roman" or "Sabon* Roman" (or whatever name -dshow-available-fonts shows).